# Call periodically a function inside subscribe while listening at the same time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Please excuse me ignorance but I have a little experience in Reactive extensions. What I want is something like this:

```
myObservable.Do(d => myObserver.OnNext(d)).Interval(someTime).subscribe({ Run the this code periodically with period T=sometime});
```

Verbally, given an observable that emits items all the time, what is needed is these items to fed continuously into an observer and every period time `T` to call a function inside the `subscribe`. Just mentioning this functions call some functions inside the `myObserver`. The above snippet does not works. It says that `myObservable` does not contain a definition of `Interval`. Could you please cast some light to the situation?

**EDIT:** The observer, process the incoming items. Thus, what I want is to listen all the time and call a start and stop process every `T`. This process has to do of collecting the items and store them. There is some start and stop `memorystream`. Thus in first time(`StartWith(-1L)`), the observer initiate some processing and after `T` seconds, stop that procedure. This start and stop loop continues periodically.

---

**EDIT #2:**

I have an `IObservable<T>` that emits items. Those items are received by an observer. This observer, can process data. What I want is to start and stop this process periodically. This means that the observer should receive data all the time and in a period of time `t`, this process has to start if is stopped or stop if it is already started/running. This `start()` `stop()` functions are members of the observer, i.e, observer.start() and observer.stop(). Also there is a flag/boolean inside the observer that is true or false if the process is running. I thought `Interval` should work but does not work with an `IObservable<T>`. Could you please cast some light to the situation?

**EDIT#3**
I think I found what I needed thanks to the discussion.

```
observable.subscribe(oberver) // observer always listening

TimeSpan someTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
IObservable<long> myObservable = Observable.Interval(someTime);

myObservable.Subscribe(d =>
    {
       if (!observer.isProcessing)
       {
           observer.Start();

        }else if (observer.isProcessing)
        {
           observer.Stop();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Try to explain the issue without referring to observers. Using observers that way is probably the wrong thing to do. Can you explain the problem in more basic steps?

Comment: @Enigmativity I have made some changes to my post. I hope that helps. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You're imposing the wrong solution on this problem. The observer shouldn't have `start()` or `stop()` - observers should be "observers", they shouldn't control the process. And, if your observer is also an `IObservable<>` then you're implementing your own and that's generally bad.

Comment: Also, please don't edit questions so that they invalidate existing answers. I've edited your question to show how this should be done.

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do - not in terms of observables and observers - in terms of what the incoming data is, how it is processed, why it need to start and stop, etc. We can then advise on the best way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

`Interval` is a static method directly off of `Observable` - it's not part of the `IObservable<T>` interface. You would use it like this:

```
TimeSpan someTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
IObservable<long> myObservable = Observable.Interval(someTime);
```

Now you can go ahead and write the code you want:

```
myObservable
    .Do(d => myObserver.OnNext(d))
    .Subscribe(d =>
    {
        //Run the this code periodically with period T=sometime
    });
```

I'm not sure why you're calling `myObserver.OnNext(d)` like that. It seems a little like a code smell. If you can add further detail to your question then perhaps I can help with that part too.

Comment: Thanks for answering. The `myObservable` send some data (a data structure to be more precise) that must pass into the `myObserver`. Tha is why I need `.Do(d => myObserver.OnNext(d))`. I think the `IObservable<long>` does not fit exactly to my needs. Can we do it in some other way? Thanks again.

Comment: Please let me know if you need other details. Also, please not, that the code example in the post, it was provided to give a general overview of the problem noting that I need something like `Interval`. Thanks again.

Comment: @Darkmoor - I think you've asked an X-Y question. You think Y is the answer to your problem X, so you've asked how to do Y. I think you should ask how to do X. You with me?

Comment: I think I have found what I was needed, thanks to the discussion and you interest. Please see **Edit 3**. Nonetheless, I am curious If we can combine those two parts. Is it possible something like that?

Comment: @Darkmoor - I can't comment on your code without being able to run it myself. The `.Start()` and `.Stop()` methods are not defined. It does appear to me that you're just trying to pace the calling of the observer code. `Interval` does that already for you. I think you need to rethink what you're doing. It would be so useful if you gave us the actual problem you're trying to solve.